# Lua Program Delay

Tags: time, lua, delay

How would I use this to add a delay of 2 minutes to my Lua program, here is the code for the delay, but I dont know how to add the delay.

```
function sleep(n)
  local t = os.clock()
  while os.clock() - t <= n do
    -- nothing
  end
end
```

Comment: Please note that `os.clock()` behaivour is not portable. Also, you're unnecessarily wasting CPU power by this busy loop. Use `socket.sleep()` from luasocket.

Comment: Okay, I will use `socket.sleep()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `os.clock` function returns the number of seconds of CPU time for the program. So the `sleep` function of yours waits for `n` seconds, if you need to delay 2 minutes, just call:

```
sleep(2*60)
```

Note that there are some better solutions to implement `sleep` functions other than busy waiting, see [Sleep Function](http://lua-users.org/wiki/SleepFunction) for detail.

Comment: Thanks, I should have known that :D

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work

```
    function sleep(n)
         n = math.ceil(n)
         if n <= 0 and n > 99999 then return end --If the user enter a number below 0 and higher than 99999 the limit in TIMEOUT command in Windows
         os.execute("timeout /T "..tostring(seconds).." /NOBREAK")
    end
```

This will not wasting CPU time by busy loop
but "Waiting for n seconds, press CTRL+C to quit ..."
In Windows you can use -1 but it will wait forever so i restrict it because waiting forever is useless. And if you don't want "Waiting for n seconds, press CTRL+C to quit ..." to appear i don't know for that can do same thing without display that. If you want get rid of that just add os.execute("cls") after the os.execute("timeout /T "..tostring(seconds).." /NOBREAK") statement and it will clear up the console